# Getting "Invalid Date" when passing dynamic date in IE 11 only in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date

Creating date using dynamically generated date string throws `invalid date` message only in `IE11`.

Example

```js
var today = new Date();
var ag_endDate = new Date(today).toLocaleDateString('en-US');
var final = new Date(ag_endDate);
console.log(final);
```

Comment: to avoid cross browser conflicts you can use momentjs (http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: `ag_endDate` in IE11 [seems to contain](https://jsfiddle.net/rx2n599h/) several `\u200e` characters. A bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
var dateObj = new Date();
var usFormatDate = dateObj.toLocaleDateString('en-US'); 
console.log( usFormatDate );
```

sorry, my bad! `date` constructor does take `date` Object as parameter.

However, if your intention is to simply get the formatted `date` in `en-US` locale, then you don't have to create another `date` object for the same.